# mysql C++ select all rows from all columns

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to select all rows from all columns in a table and output them to a string, i tried to increment the resultset and append each row to a string but that didn't work.

The only way i can get it to work is if i manually change the resultset.getString() but that will only show 1 full row.

```
    sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
```

As you can see on the 2nd last line "cout << res->getString(1) << endl;" they select the 1st column manually.

Would it be possible to select all columns so that it outputs all rows in all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

In the end, this will get you what you need...

```
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet  *res;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

  /* Connect to the MySQL so_test database */
  con->setSchema("so_test");
  stmt = con->createStatement();

  // Select all columns/rows from example_table
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM example_table");

  //get result set metadata
  sql::ResultSetMetaData *res_meta = res -> getMetaData();
  int columns = res_meta -> getColumnCount();

  //Loop for each row
  while (res->next()) {
    /* Access column data by index, 1-indexed*/
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
      cout << res->getString(i) << "|" ;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And don't forget to include

```
#include <resultset_metadata.h>
```

Comment: I can't seem to run "mysql_num_rows()", any ideas? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I can however get it through Resultset metadata which i tried already and it only outputs the first column rows.

Comment: Correction, it crashes when i run it.